# How do I use Xor in VB without using the built-in one?

Tags: vb.net, function, xor

I want to use Xor without using the built-in one in Visual Basic .NET

Xor description:

> It is the logical as well as bitwise Logical Exclusive OR operator.
>
> It returns True if both expressions are True or both expressions are False; otherwise it returns False.
>
> This operator does not perform short-circuiting, it always evaluates both expressions and there is no short-circuiting counterpart of this operator

Is this even possible? And if so, how?

Comment: Whats wrong with the "built-in one" ?

Comment: I can't see how this would be possible.  How can it test if both expressions evaluate to the same boolean value if it doesn't evaluate both expressions?

Comment: I just want to know if it's possible not to use the built-in one.

Comment: What you've described under "Xor" description is the negation of Xor. Xor returns true if 1, and only 1 expression is True.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XOR is simply a logical operation. If you wanted, you could replace it entirely with NANDs, since NAND is functionally complete.

XOR could be

```
(a and not b) or (not a and b)
```

or

```
(a or b) and (not a or not b)
```

or if you don't want logical operators at all...

```
If(a) Then
    If(not b) Then
        Return True
    End If
Else If(not a) Then
    If(b) Then
        Return True
    End If
End If
Return False
```

So basically, yes - I imagine there are a myriad of ways that you could do this. But I can't think of why you would ever want to.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that definition is not correct. Exclusive OR means that one and only one of the expressions are true. That definition is Exclusive NOR.

But anyway

```
XOR:
(bool1 and not bool2) or (not bool1 and bool2)

XNOR:
(bool1 and bool2) or (not bool1 and not bool2)
```

Or even simply

```
bool1 = bool2
```

Answer (score 0):

The definition stated for XOR is incorrect, as other have noted.  XOR is simply addition without carry.

```
    Dim b1 As Boolean = False
    Dim b2 As Boolean = False

    For x As Integer = 1 To 2
        For y As Integer = 1 To 2
            Dim n1 As Integer = CInt(b1)
            Dim n2 As Integer = CInt(b2)
            Dim ans As Boolean = CBool((n1 + n2) And 1) 'add, ignore carries
            Debug.WriteLine("b1 {0}  b2 {1}   ans {2}", b1, b2, ans)
            b2 = Not b2
        Next
        b1 = Not b1
    Next
```

Answer (score 0):

`Dim val1, val2 As Boolean`
`If Val1 <> Val2 Return False`
`Else Return True`
`End If`

'That is XNOR